# Привязка в html и css!

Tags: jquery, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста! Я пытаюсь привязать текст-ссылку к фотографии но у меня не получается, подскажите как можно это сделать? Может можно как то на jquery?

Вот текст html.

```
<div id="foto">
<a href=""><img  src="img/img7.jpg" alt="" /></a>
<div id="cap">
<p><a href="">Продукт компании</a></p>
</div>
</div>
```

Вот css!

```
#cap {
  z-index: 1000;
  height:35px;  
  background:#000;  
  background:rgba(0,0,0,.5);    
  width:332px;
  font-size:1em;

  color:#fff;

  border-top:1px solid #000;

  text-align:center;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Что значит привязать ? Можно поподробнее суть вопроса.

Comment: Я создал прозрачную слегка затемненную полосу с ссылкой по середине и пытаюсь ее позиционировать в низу фотографии. Мне надо чтобы при дальнейшем position:absolute;-фотографии, затемненная полоса с ссылкой всегда находилась в фотографии.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как то так должно сработать:

```
<div class="photo">
    <a href="/"><img src="img1.jpg" alt=""/></a>
    <div class="photo-title">
        Супер картинка
    </div>
</div>

<style>
    .photo {
        position: relative;
    }
    .photo-title {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        width: 100%;
        color: #fff;
        background: rgba(40,40,40,0.5);
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Класс! Спасибо! Очень вам благодарен что вы мне сразу ответили!

Comment: Пожал бы вам руку если бы мог:)

Comment: Можно просто поставить палец вверх, рядом с вопросом и пометить его как правильный ответ:)

Comment: Руку не пожмете, а ответ могли бы и принять, повысив в качестве благодарности человеку репутацию на форуме! :P

Comment: Если можно ответе еще на вопрос? как можно такие же три фотографии с ссылками-.photo-title расположить по горизонтали при этом дать промежуток между первой и второй, второй и третьей фотографией? border-spacing не подходит так как дает промежуток не только по внутренним отступам но и по внешним, а мне надо по внутренним.

Comment: В комментариях не будет форматирования кода. Если без кода, то вам нужно для .photo задать display: inline-block; margin-left: 20px; И далее .photo:first-child {margin-left: 0;}
Это должно работать если каждая строка ваших фотографий будет в контейнере, если нет там ответ чуть посложнее и желательно наличие форматирования.

Comment: Еще вам бесплатный совет, старайтесь давать значения атрибутам не транслитом, коим по сути является foto(это только на немецком фотография), а на нормальном английском. Люди будут вам благодарны.